# firebase login wrong password

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need help, i keep getting an error where, whenever i log in it keeps saying wrong password even though i typed it correctly, registering the account is fine and it auto logs in but the moment i sign out the account, refresh and then log in it keeps saying wrong password, can anyone help me with this?

```
function loginbtn(){
 //[then signs in the new user]
 var loginEmail = document.getElementById('txtEmail').value;
 var loginPass = document.getElementById('txtPass').value;
 if (loginEmail.lenght <= 0){
 alert('Please enter an email address.');
}
if (loginPass.lenght <= 0){
alert('Please enter a password.');
} 

// Sign in with email and pass.
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(loginEmail, loginPass).catch(function(error){
 // Handle Errors here.
 var errorCode = error.code;
 var errorMsg = error.message;
 // [START_EXCLUDE]
 if (errorCode ==='auth/wrong-password'){
  alert('Wrong password.');
 } else {
  alert(errorMsg);
 }
 console.log(error);
 document.getElementById('btnLogin').disabled = false;
});
// [END authwithemail]
//disables the button after logging in
document.getElementById('btnLogin').disabled = true;  
}
```

Comment: How did you implement logout?

Comment: i made it as an event listener on the same js file like this
signout.addEventListener('click',e =>{
      firebase.auth().signOut(); });

and then created a button with the same id(signout)

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to signin correctly:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(loginEmail , loginPass)
   .then(function(firebaseUser) {
       // Success 
   })
  .catch(function(error) {
       // Error Handling
  });
```